# How to play m3u8 streaming when available in Android?

Tags: android

I have a live m3u8 streaming that I play in a VideoView in Android as follows :

```
    MyVideoView.setVideoPath(this.VideoURL);
    MyVideoView.start();
```

This code works properly when the streaming is already playing. But when it's not, I'm getting a popup saying "Can not play the video"

Is there anyway to force the VideoView play the streaming when it's available? If it's not available, it will just wait and then play it when it resumes.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use ExoPlayer [ExoPlayer Android Integration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) if you are comfortable with it.

Or use videoView.setOnpreparedListener() and videoview.prepareasync().

Personally, Exoplayer is good for video playing than VideoView because it provides better control.